# Parsing json in angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to read the count of users in my angular2 application from services.
We have a swagger generate the stub from the service.

My stub (gpMapApi):

```
 public findMapByIdsUsingGET(oId?: number, id?: number, extraHttpRequestParams?: any): Observable<string> {
        return this.findMapByIdsUsingGET(oId, id, extraHttpRequestParams)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            });
    }
```

My Json response:

```
{"count" : 0}
```

My Typescript

```
public checkUserExist(oId,Id) {
       this.gpMapApi.findMapByIdsUsingGET(oId,id)
             .subscribe(response => {
                  if ((<any>response) !== null && (<any>response)['_body'] !== null && (<any>response)['_body']['count'] !== null) {
                this.iCount = (<any>response)['_body']['count'];
        });      
    }
```

But I get error saying "count" is undefined.
Error  message from chrome

```
"Cannot read property 'count' of undefined"
```

how to read the json response.

Solution 
Used 
 JSON.parse((response)._body).count

Comment: This is the error I am getting                                                                          Property 'json' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: can you log the response: `console.log(response)`?

Comment: Response _body : "{"count" : 0}"

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(response)`?

Comment: in your post, you said that "My Json response:" `{"count" : 0}`. Then use directly `response['count']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are returning `undefined` but your checks in your Typescript are checking for `null` [where `!==` means ***strictly** not equal*]

If you change it to `!=` that should perhaps fix your issue. If not, it will definitely not crash, and follow your *if condition* correctly.

#### Edit:

If you are having JSON parsing issues and your `response` variable is a string then you can to `JSON.parse(response)` instead of `response.json()` to get your Object.

#### Edit Final:

Ok based on your comment, it's evident that the `(<any>response)._body` is a String, which is verifiable by running `typeof (<any>response)._body`. Based on this the solution is simply `JSON.parse((<any>response)._body).count`.

Comment: After modifying the code, it did not go inside the loop.

Comment: Right that means that `(<any>response)['_body']` is `undefined`. I would recommend `console.log(<any>response)` to figure out which keys are set, and if you may be using the wrong key

Comment: This is my Response Response
_body
:
"{"count" : 0}", I am not sure how to retrieve the value 0. If I try this console.log('response', (<any>response)['_body']['_count']); I get response undefined. But console.log('response', (<any>response)['_body']); gets {"count": 0}

Comment: Thanks, this worked Soln: JSON.parse((<any>response)._body).count